# Counting number of rows between min and max in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple question in pandas.

Lets say I have following data:

```
d = {'a': [1, 3, 5, 2, 10, 3, 5, 4, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

How do I count the number of rows which are between minimum and maximum value in column a? So number of rows (it is 3 in this case) which are between 1 and 10 in this particular case?

Thanks

Comment: Can the max be before the min? What do you want to do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could get the index of the min and max, and subtract 2:

```
out = len(df.loc[df['a'].idxmin():df['a'].idxmax()])-2
```

output: `3`

If the is a chance that the max is before the min:

```
out = max(len(df.loc[df['a'].idxmin():df['a'].idxmax()])-2, 0)
```

Alternative it the order of the min/max does not matter:

```
import numpy as np
out = np.ptp(df.reset_index()['a'].agg(['idxmin', 'idxmax']))-1
```

##### update: index of the 2nd largest/smallest:

```
# second largest
df['a'].nlargest(2).idxmin()
# 2

# second smallest
df['a'].nsmallest(2).idxmax()
# 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This mostly suits my real problem. One additional question,  Can one use idmax() to get the second maximum value? So that you can count number of the rows between the first and the second maximum values? It might not make sense here, as second max value is duplicated. But rather the case where second max value is unique.

Comment: @Avto you cannot directly get the 2nd max. You'd need to use nlargest/nsmallest, filter and then get the indices of the found values. A bit more work, I provided an example as an update

Comment: Regarding the duplicates, note that `idxmax`/`idxmin` only return the **first** max/min. For `nlargest`/`nsmallest` you can chose which one (see doc).

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
diff = np.abs(df['a'].idxmin() - df['a'].idxmax()) - 1
```

Comment: This however only works if the index is a range

Answer (score 2):

Since they are numbers, we can dump down into numpy and compute the result:

```py
arr = df.a.to_numpy()
np.abs(np.argmax(arr) - np.argmin(arr)) - 1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
np.abs(df.loc[df.a==df.a.min()].index-df.loc[df.a==df.a.max()].index)-1
```